# Searching for a word in a sentence in MIPS

Tags: search, assembly, mips, sentence

I hope you're all having a great day. I was hoping i could get some assistance with my project code. Basically a sentence "FADED IN FADED OUT." is type in when prompted and then a search word "FADED" is typed in and the code is executed to see if the word "FADED" is in the sentence and if it is it will say "x Match(es) Found" and if not "No Match(es) Found". Well when I compile and run it gives me a "line 65: Runtime exception at 0x00400098: address out of range 0x00000000" error and there are multiple lines that have this error. Would anyone be able to assist me with this? I have been trying to do it the past 3 days and finally broke for some help... If you have any questions please let me know!

```
    .data

    str: .space 100                 # Pre Allocate space for the input sentence
    input: .space 30                # Pre Allocate space for the input sentence 
    ins: .asciiz "Please enter a sentence: "    # string to print sentence
    seek: .asciiz "Please enter a word: "       # string to print sentence 
    nomatch: .asciiz "No Match(es) Found"           
    found: .asciiz " Match(es) Found"
    newline: .asciiz "\n"               # string to print newline

    .text

    li $v0, 4       # syscall to print string
    la $a0, ins     # move str into a0
    syscall         # syscall 

    li $a1, 100     # allocate space for the string
    la $a0, str     # load address of the input string
    li, $v0, 8      # read string input from user
    syscall         # issue a system call

    move $t9, $a0       # move string to t5

    li $v0, 4       # syscall to print string
    la $a0, seek        # move str into a0
    syscall         # syscall 

    la $a0, input       # load address of the input string
    li $a2, 30      # allocate space for the string
    li, $v0, 8      # read string input from user
    syscall         # issue a system call

    move $t8, $a0       # move string to t8
    la $s5, input       # create space for the input word we are looking for in s5

    wloop:          # loop to allocate space for the word we are looking for to a register
    lb $t0, 0($t8)      # load first character into t0
    beqz $t0, sentence  # branch to sentence loop if null character
    sb $t0, 0($s5)      # store the current character into current address of s5
    addi $t8, $t8, 1    # add one to t8 to move to next character
    addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to the next allocated space
    j wloop         # jump back to wloop

    la $s4, str     # create space for the input sentence

    sentence:       # loop to allocate space for the word we are looking for into a register
    lb $t0, 0($t9)      # load first character into t0
    beqz $t0, resetsen  # branch to check loop if null character
    sb $t9, 0($s4)      # store the current character into current address of s4
    addi $t9, $t9, 1    # add one to t9 to move to next character
    addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s5 to move to the next allocated space
    j sentence      # jump back to sentence

    resetsen:
    li $s4, 0       # reset sentence back to 0 (first character)

    resetword:
    li $s5, 0       # reset word we are looking for back to 0 (first character)

    check:
    lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
    beq $t1, 46, quit   # branch to QUIT if period found
    bne $t1, 70, nextword   # if t1 != t0 branch to nextword
    beq $t1, 70, checkword  # branch to found if t1 = f

    nextword:       # loop to get to the next word
    lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character to t1
    beq $t1, 46, quit   # branch to quit if period found
    bne $t1, 32, increment  # if current character is not a spaace branch to increment
    beq $t1, 32, plusone    # if current character is a space branch to plusone
    increment:      # increment procedure
    addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
    j nextword      # jump to nextword
    plusone:        # plusone procedure
    addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
    j resetword     # jump to check

    checkword:
    addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
    addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to next character
    lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
    lb $t0, 0($s5)      # load current character of sentence to t0
    bne $t1, $t0, increment # if t0 != t1 branch to increment (looking for a)
    addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
    addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to next character
    lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
    lb $t0, 0($s5)      # load current character of sentence to t0
    bne $t1, $t0, increment # if t0 != t1 branch to increment (looking for d)
    addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
    addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to next character
    lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
    lb $t0, 0($s5)      # load current character of sentence to t0
    bne $t1, $t0, increment # if t0 != t1 branch to increment (looking for e)
    addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
    addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to next character
    lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
    lb $t0, 0($s5)      # load current character of sentence to t0
    bne $t1, $t0, increment # if t0 != t1 branch to increment (looking for d)
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    # add one to t2 which counts occurences
    j resetword

    quit:
    beqz $t2, exit      # if t2 = 0 branch to exit
    li $v0, 1       # syscall to print integer
    move $a0, $t2       # move str into a0
    syscall         # syscall 
    li $v0, 4       # syscall to print string
    la $a0, found       # move found into a0
    syscall         # syscall 
    j endprogram

    exit:
    li $v0, 4       # syscall to print string
    la $a0, nomatch     # move nomatch into a0
    syscall         # syscall 

    endprogram:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: You know the address where the exception occurs, so you can easily check which line of code that corresponds to in SPIM/MARS. I think MARS will even highlight that line of code for you. And then you could use the single-step feature to step upto that point and watch the registers along the way. Hint: when you use a register as a base address (i.e. inside the `()` in a load/store instruction) you need to pay close attention to what values you've put in those registers.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I don't know how that would be done. Would I be stepping up the 0 in front of the parenthesis?

Comment: By stepping I mean executing the instructions in your program one-by-one when you press a key / click a button in the simulator. It's easier to follow what happens in the code that way.

Comment: Ok thank you I will look into that and see what I can do. I have been teaching myself this language and its a headache! Lol. Appreciate it!